# angular service is not working

Tags: angular, typeahead

I am establishing a service between two components and it's not working as expected. can you please suggest me what is missing. When the user selected the value from the typeahead, then that value pass on to a search component to find the details for that selected value. typeahead and search are two different components.

```
 /* html */
 <input id="typeahead-http" type="text" class="form-control" [class.is-invalid]="searchFailed" (ngModelChange)="onCapture()" [(ngModel)]="model" [ngbTypeahead]="search" placeholder="control" />


 /* service */
 import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
 import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';
 @Injectable()
 export class DataService {
   private keyword = new BehaviorSubject<string>("abc");
   currentKeyword = this.keyword.asObservable();

   constructor() { }
   changeKeyword(message: string) {
      this.keyword.next(message)
    }   
  }


 /* component that sends data */
 export class MedtypeaheadComponent {
 constructor(private _service: WikipediaService, private data: 
  DataService) {}

 onCapture() {
     this.data.changeKeyword("happy");
 }

}

/* component receives data */
export class SearchComponent {

rows = [];
keyword = null;
constructor(private http: Http, private data: DataService) {}
onSearch(): void {
    this.data.currentKeyword.subscribe(keyword => this.keyword = keyword );
    var data = { 'search' : this.keyword };
    console.log(data);
}
  }
```

Comment: Have you registered the service as a provider in your module?

Comment: Yes. I did. thanks.

Comment: Have you registered the service as provider in components as well?

Comment: Yes. I did. I did not get any error messages.